# Betta dying help

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, betta, water-parameters

I forgot to save the old water from when I cleaned my betta’s tank and now he’s floating at the bottom. What can I do? I have already tried putting my guppies’ tank water in to do half half and it’s still not working.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! To float on the bottom is a sign of stress. To change the whole water is stressful, like moving into a complete new environment. The tank water of your guppies will not help much with this stress. But maybe the water will have less additives, than the water from common taps. I assume you should do a water test, and add the results here. This will help the experienced users to answer your question.

Comment: Please click the [edit] button after you did your water test and add the results to your question. That will (hopefully) allow us to give you a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems (without seeing water test results) that you shocked your fish by doing too much change at once. It's always good to do daily and small changes to your betta aquarium (if you don't have filtration system) or 20-30% weekly with filtration. You never do too much stressful changes, as our fishes are very sensitive.

Let us know how it continues and please try to stabilize its environment as more sudden changes won't help.